# Where does ripple emulator create files?

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, google-chrome, ripple

I create a file with ripple emulator successfully at this path:

```
fullPath: "/myAppFolder/myFile.txt"
```

This is the code:

```
filesystem.root.getDirectory(
  "myAppFolder",
  { create: true, exclusive: false },
  function(dir) {
    dir.getFile(
      "myFile.txt",
      { create: true, exclusive: true },
      function(file) {
        console.log(file);
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log("error create file: " + error.code + ":" + error.message);
      }
    );
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log("error create dir: " + error.code + ":" + error.message);
  }
);
```

Also where can I see this file? Is it on the hard drive?

Comment: are you saying your phonegap application created that file on a device at that location?

Comment: sorry, my application using phonegap and file plugin created that file.

Comment: phonegap can create apps for a number of device platforms, does your device have a file manager so you can browse the folders in the internal storage and/or sd card?

Comment: Exactly this is my question, because I am testing my app on my pc with the ripple emulator.